# Oracle case function

Tags: oracle

The below expression is not working,actually i want to update sal and desg based on below condition using case

```
SELECT SAL,
CASE SAL  WHEN     SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000 THEN SAL=SAL+(0.2*SAL) AND DESG='DEO'
          WHEN     SAL BETWEEN 5001 AND 7000 THEN SAL=SAL+(.15*SAL) AND DESG='ENGNRR'
          WHEN     SAL  BETWEEN 7001 AND 10000 THEN SAL=SAL+(0.25*SAL) AND DESG='SSE'
          WHEN     SAL >1000 THEN SAL=SAL +(0.15*SAL) AND DESG='PSE'
              `    `ELSE SAL=SAL+1500 AND DESG='TL'
              END 
               FROM SAMPLES
```

My Table name is samples

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? giving an error? Giving wrong results? you don't know how to make this an update statment?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you find something useful on how to ask a good question

Comment: well for start you need `UPDATE` statment to update `sal`.

Comment: Did you really mean to test when `SAL>1000`? From the pattern of previous values it appears like you are missing a zero.

Answer (score 1):

well for start you need `UPDATE` statment to update `sal`.

Secon after `THEN` can only be one expresion, not `AND` comparators. If you want create two columns you need to use two `CASE` expresion

```
SELECT SAL,
       CASE WHEN SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000 THEN SAL+(0.2*SAL)   -- == SAL * 1.2
            WHEN SAL BETWEEN 5001 AND 7000 THEN SAL+(.15*SAL)   -- == SAL * 1.15
            WHEN SAL BETWEEN 7001 AND 10000 THEN SAL+(0.25*SAL) -- == SAL * 1.25
            WHEN SAL > 1000 THEN SAL +(0.15*SAL)                -- == SAL * 1.15
            ELSE SAL+1500
       END as newSal,
       CASE WHEN SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000 THEN 'DEO'
            WHEN SAL BETWEEN 5001 AND 7000 THEN 'ENGNRR'
            WHEN SAL BETWEEN 7001 AND 10000 THEN 'SSE'
            WHEN SAL > 1000 THEN 'PSE'
            ELSE 'TL'
       END as newDSG
FROM SAMPLES;
```

Also you dont assing Values on the `CASE`, you need and update

```
UPDATE SAMPLES
SET SAL = CASE WHEN SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000 THEN SAL+(0.2*SAL) 
               WHEN SAL BETWEEN 5001 AND 7000 THEN SAL+(.15*SAL)
               WHEN SAL BETWEEN 7001 AND 10000 THEN SAL+(0.25*SAL)
               WHEN SAL > 1000 THEN SAL +(0.15*SAL)
               ELSE SAL+1500
          END,
DESG = CASE WHEN SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000 THEN 'DEO'
            WHEN SAL BETWEEN 5001 AND 7000 THEN 'ENGNRR'
            WHEN SAL BETWEEN 7001 AND 10000 THEN 'SSE'
            WHEN SAL > 1000 THEN 'PSE'
            ELSE 'TL'
       END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SAMPLES
SET SAL  = CASE WHEN SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000  THEN SAL*1.2
                WHEN SAL > 5000 AND SAL <= 7000 THEN SAL*1.15
                WHEN SAL > 7000 AND SAL <=10000 THEN SAL*1.25
                WHEN SAL >10000                 THEN SAL*1.15
                                                ELSE SAL+1500
                END,
   DESG = CASE WHEN SAL BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000  THEN 'DEO'
               WHEN SAL > 5000 AND SAL <= 7000 THEN 'ENGNRR'
               WHEN SAL > 7000 AND SAL <=10000 THEN 'SSE'
               WHEN SAL >10000                 THEN 'PSE'
                                               ELSE 'TL'
               END;
```